# Clipboard change event code is complicated and isn't working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, clipboard, dllimport

I want to show the clipboard in a textbox as its content changes, I understand that I need to use imports from "user32.dll", but I have never used these kinds of imports and they are a bit confusing for me. I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621577/clipboard-event-c-sharp) link and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226920/how-to-monitor-clipboard-content-changes-in-c) link to get some ideas about Clipboard change event, so here are my questions:
**1. Even though I copied and pasted the codes from the links above, they still don't work:**
[image: error1]
WndProc's error is: *'object' does not contain a definition for 'WndProc'*

**2. I'd like to know more about the user32.dll and kernel32.dll imports, if possible, please provide some information about them, or provide some sources that explain the basics of these.**
Thank you

Comment: If you know nothing at all about Win32, then you are on a hiding to nothing. You should start by working with a C++ test project that does what you need. Learn what you need of Win32 that way. Learning Win32 with p/invoke is just asking for pain.

Comment: You need a class with a message pump to get WndProc().  This is typically a Form or Control, but you can also use NativeWindow.  Your class simply derives from the base Object class, which doesn't have WndProc.  In [my example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20029427/2330053), I demonstrate how to use the NativeWindow approach.

Comment: `base.WndProc` makes no sense in this case, since your `ClipboardManager` class has no explicitly defined base class - so it descends from `Object`, which does not have a `WndProc` method.

Comment: @DavidLively yes you're right how silly of me! thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To monitor Clipboard in a form, you should create your form first , then use these codes, for example:

```
public class Form1: Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += Form1_Load;
    }

    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr SetClipboardViewer(IntPtr hWndNewViewer);

    public const int WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD = 0x0308;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetClipboardViewer(this.Handle);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg != WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD)
            return;
        //Code To handle Clipboard change event
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`

Comment: this gave me a few good ideas about my code, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @ImanIrt I've checked the code and it works. What's the problem?

Comment: I put the code 'textbox1.Text = "Clipboard changed" ' in the comment section that you provided (Code to handle clipboard change event) but I don't get anything when I copy something to clipboard.

Comment: @ImanIrt You should call `SetClipboardViewer` somewhere, for example in your form load.

Comment: @ImanIrt :) you are welcome, I edited the answer to be more clear. Also you can continue using `AddClipboardFormatListener` that you were using, this way.